# array containing an object without using a data structure

Tags: apiblueprint

I'm currently using the following. It works, but I'd like to bake it into one data structure. This means moving the status and title into the array somehow. Is this possible?

```
## Invalid Credentials Object (object)

+ status: 401 (number)
+ title: `Invalid Credentials`

## Invalid Credentials (object)

+ errors (array[Invalid Credentials Object])
```

I'd like it to somehow resemble:

```
## Invalid Credentials (object)

+ errors (array[
    + status: 401 (number)
    + title: `Invalid Credentials`
])
```

Comment: I think we are going to need a little more information than you have provided.

Comment: @SteveMatthews I apologize! As you can see I have two data structures `Invalid Credentials Object` and `Invalid Credentials`. I'd like to merge them into one!

Comment: `Invalid Credentials` uses `Invalid Credentials Object` in it's array.

Comment: Is this in any particular language?  I can tell you how to do it in RPGLE 4 on an IBM AS/400 server if that helps?

Comment: Ah, well api blueprint uses MSON afaiak: https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/blob/master/API%20Blueprint%20Specification.md

Comment: @SteveMatthews Also here: https://apiblueprint.org/documentation/mson/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

Could you not do something like;

```
# Invalid Credentials (object)

+ errors (array[
      #error
          + status: 401 (number)
          + message: 'Invalid Credentials'
      ])
```

Of course that's assuming you can next objects within an array.